# Как при ошибках валидации в Yii2 загружать определенную страницу?

Tags: yii, валидация, регистрация

Здравствуйте. У меня немного непродуманная ситуация вышла, может кто подскажет, как сделать нормально?)

У меня на одной вьюшке есть 2 формы входа и регистрации на сайте. По умолчанию открывается форма входа.
Работает это все через волшебные свойства js и css-ки, то есть нажимаешь вход->появляется форма входа, регистрация->та красиво исчезает и появляется вторая форма.

В адресной строке это выглядит жутковато, якорями, вот так:

`site/login#signin`

`site/login#signup`

В итоге, когда регистрируешься, то при ошибке валидации страница перезагружается и снова становится формой логина. Чтобы увидеть эти ошибки, надо опять нажимать на "зарегистрироваться".

Как сделать так, чтобы он открывал форму регистрации?

Когда прописываю редирект или рефреш, ошибки валидации слетают, открывает нужную форму, но при этом она совершенно новенькая(

`if($modelSignUp->validate() && $modelSignUp->signup()){ 
    return $this->goHome(); 
} 
else{
    return $this->redirect('login#signup'); 
}`

И еще, чисто теоретически, спасет ли тут **валидация на стороне клиента или ajax-валидация**? (спрашиваю, а не пробую, потому что УЖЕ не получилось:D)

Comment: Делаете проверку во время валидации и добавляете редирект на нужный адрес (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html)

Comment: Когда прописываю редирект или рефреш, ошибки валидации слетают, открывает нужную форму, при этом она совершенно новенькая( 

`if($modelSignUp->validate() && $modelSignUp->signup()){
              return $this->goHome();
            }
            else{
              return $this->redirect('login#signup');
            }`

Или это не то, о чем я думаю?

Comment: Ошибки валидации хранятся в $FormModel->errors, это обычный массив, который можно использовать при передаче во вьюшку или куда-то еще, и уже там использовать для вывода на экран. Вы можете даже присвоить их другой форме если нужно.

Comment: Это очень интересно и могло бы подойти, однако самостоятельно мне не удалось найти такой пример, вы не могли бы привести какую-нибудь ссылочку или фрагмент кода, как передать массив с ошибками и вывести их у формы заново после редиректа?

Comment: Всё оттуда же - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html - Вам нужно добавить во вьюшку код: <?= $form->errorSummary($model) ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге ларчик открывался довольно просто. Ура!
Дело в использовании Url хелпера вместе со ссылкой, всего-то. 
Если кому пригодится, хелпер подключить не забудьте и поставить метод отправки POST.
Долго пришлось искать решение, потому что невнимательность не позволила увидеть, что **метод надо прописывать в дополнительном массиве параметров 'data'** и нежелание читать про хелперы до этой минуты:)

```
<?= Html::a('Зарегистрироваться', ['login', '#' => 'signup'], [
                'data' => [
                    'method' => 'post',
                ],
                'class' => 'btn btn-default submit',
                'name' => 'signup-button'
            ]);
             ?>
```